# Android Expandable ListView State not saving Properly on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Hi Everyone iam having trouble with expandable Listview inside fragment while orientation change . i have a list fragment on left and on click of item details fragment will be shown on right; on details fragment user has chance to edit items in the expandable listview whenver user enter his details and perform a orientation change all the data entered in expandable lsitview child is reset i tried using all options like my activity is not recreating on orientation change and also used setRetainInstance(true); but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the content of your EditText / TextView / whatever in `onSaveInstanceState`, and store them in the bundle. When you Activity / Fragment gets recreated, retrieve your content from the bundle in `onCreate`.